# Arraylist of image call from another activity and try to show in list view

Tags: java, android

```
public class ViewPDF extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<Uri> list;
ArrayAdapter<Uri> adapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_pdf);

    Intent intent = new Intent();

    ArrayList<Uri> arrayList = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("multipleImage");

    ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.imageList);

    list = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Uri>(this, R.layout.listview_layout, R.id.imageView, list);
    
    for(int i=0; i < arrayList.size(); i++){
        list.add(arrayList.get(i));
    }


    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

I am trying to get image arrayList from other activity then try to show all image in a list view. what is the error ? Nothing is showing on logcat.

Comment: Try to print the size of arrayList after `ArrayList<Uri> arrayList = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("multipleImage");` this line

Comment: Based on your code structure, you should set this line after for loop.

adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Uri>(this, R.layout.listview_layout, R.id.imageView, list);